# How to mask a string in swift 4.2

Tags: swift4.2

I wanna make a mask in a string.

```js
let unmasked = "12345678900"
//string masked = "123.456.789-00"
```

This is the braziliam CPF format, i found nothing in Stack Overflow BR

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using a character array and array.insert to insert mask in defined index

Portuguese: 
Eu encontrei uma solução usando um array de caracteres e a função array.insert que permite inserir qualquer string em um determinado index da matriz.

```js
let cpf = "12345678900"
var characters = Array(cpf) //making a character array (criando um array de caracteres)

characters.insert(".", at: 3) //inserting "." in index 3 (inserindo "." no index 3) 
//character = ["1","2","3",".","4","5","6","7","8","9","0","0"]

characters.insert(".", at: 7) // inserting "." in index 7 (inserindo "." no index 7)
//character = ["1","2","3",".","4","5","6",".","7","8","9","0","0"]

characters.insert("-", at: 11)// inserting "." in index 11 (inserindo "." no index 11)
//character = ["1","2","3",".","4","5","6",".","7","8","9","-","0","0"]

let masked = String(characters) //convert character to string
pint("cpf masked: ",masked)
//the masked will show: 123.456.789-00 (a mascara irá mostrar: 123.456.789-00)
```